# Declare a `date_time_part` constant in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BQ query that aggregates records over some interval and then drops the most recent record. This means I have to define a date_time_part in two places. I'd like to use `DECLARE` or some other way of creating a constant but I can't get DECLARE to let me use the date_time_part as the type (which I think is the problem).

Example

```
WITH groups AS (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) as num_records, -- something I expect to get 12 of per hour
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, HOUR) as grouped_hour
  FROM table
  GROUP BY grouped_hour
)
SELECT * FROM groups
WHERE num_records < 12 AND TIMESTAMP_DIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), ts) > 1
```

When I add `DECLARE aggregation_window date_time_part DEFAULT HOUR;` I get an error from BQ `Type not found: date_time_part at [1:28]` but in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types) I find no reference to HOUR or MINUTE. I guess this is because they are keywords?

Comment: afaik, there is no way to pass *data_time_part* to a query via a variable except using a dynamic sql.  Other alternative is to use `CASE` expression in your query, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> afaik, there is no way to pass data_time_part to a query via a variable except using a dynamic sql. Other alternative is to use CASE expression in your query, I think.

You can consider below.

###### Dynamic SQL

```sql
DECLARE aggregation_window DEFAULT 'HOUR';

CREATE TEMP TABLE `sample_table` AS 
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  TIMESTAMP '2023-03-17 01:20:20', '2023-03-17 01:30:30', '2023-02-17 02:30:30'
]) ts;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
CREATE TEMP TABLE `groups` AS 
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_records, -- something I expect to get 12 of per hour
       TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, %s) as grouped_hour
  FROM `sample_table`
 GROUP BY grouped_hour;
""", aggregation_window);

SELECT * FROM `groups`
 WHERE num_records < 12 -- AND TIMESTAMP_DIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), ts) > 1;
```

- [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate)

##### `CASE` expression

```sql
DECLARE aggregation_window DEFAULT 'DAY';

CREATE TEMP TABLE `sample_table` AS 
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  TIMESTAMP '2023-03-17 01:20:20', '2023-03-17 01:30:30', '2023-02-17 02:30:30'
]) ts;

WITH `groups` AS (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) as num_records, -- something I expect to get 12 of per hour
    
    CASE aggregation_window
      WHEN 'HOUR' THEN TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, HOUR) 
      WHEN 'DAY' THEN  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY) 
      -- and more...
     END AS grouped_hour
  FROM `sample_table`
  GROUP BY grouped_hour
)
SELECT * FROM `groups` WHERE num_records < 12;
```